# шкала по логарифму в матплотлиб

Tags: python, matplotlib

ребята, сможете подсказать, как в matplotlib настроить шкалу X по логарифму? пока написал такой код:

```
plt.scatter(df_stat.ik, df_stat.z, alpha = .5)
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.xlabel('ik')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.xscale('log')`.

Comment: Вообще поиском же легко ищутся подобные вопросы